# How do you get the solutions to cipher puzzles?

Tags: cipher

I am new to this site and joined the community when [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11522/my-friend-is-lost-in-time?rq=1) question caught my eye.

Did the person who solved the puzzle use computer program of some kind to deduce the answer?
I don't think it is possible to come up with the answer in any other way.

Comment: Did you read the last spoiler of that answer?

Comment: Part of solving puzzles is being attentive to EVERYTHING, since you don't know up front the value it gives. In this case, it offered up a plain explanation of how the solution was derived. TL;DR; summaries are not useful. READ EVERYTHING.

Answer (score 3):

The answer given by the person who solved the puzzle explains how they found it. I don't see any reason to disbelieve them.

There were a few hints in the question; the first indicates that the ciphertext is longer than the plaintext (suggesting looking at groups of more than one letter), the second observes that there are a lot of As and Bs (suggesting looking at where they occur), and the third suggests treating letters A..Z as corresponding to numbers 0..25 somehow.

And then, as that answer says:

> All three paragraphs have length divisible by 3, suggesting that each 3-letter sequence represents a single unit.
>
> Doing frequency analysis for all 3-letter sequences showed that the two most frequent sequences were UQB (20,16,1) and PLB (15,11,1) - both ended with B(1) and had a difference of 4 (E) between the first two letters, suggesting I was on to something.
>
> The rest was just plugging the values generated by the above algorithm into the 3-letter sequences ending with B, getting much of the letters and easily figuring out what the rule for sequencing ending with A is.

Comment: "...each 3-letter sequence represents a single unit...." could you please explain?

Comment: The solver noticed that the paragraphs all had numbers of letters that would let you divide them into groups of 3, and guessed that each group of 3 corresponded to a single letter in the original plaintext.